how to register a microservice in multiple eureka server ? is it possible if yes how to do that
eureka:
client:
serviceUrl:
defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/,http://localhost:8762/eureka
instance:
prefer-ip-address: true
management:
endpoints:
web:
exposure:
include: "*"
i was hoping it will register in multiple eureka server but its only registering only on one service

By default the Eureka client will attempt to register sequentially with each server until successful.
To register with another server, you can configure zones and enable the configuration: preferSameZoneEureka: true
Additionally, in environments with multiple Eureka servers deployed, you need to register Eureka servers with each other so that the servers can share registry information.
